# Aspect ratio for background-image, when data is image/jpeg;base64

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `background-image` set to `data:image/jpeg;base64` format:

```
<div style="background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...
```

I would like to show full image respecting aspect ratio, using available space. I would normally use:

```
width: 90vw;
height: 100vh;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

In this case image is stretched using full div size. Any suggestions?

Update: 
Div with data: 
http://jsfiddle.net/witepo/bksmhtwc/

Update 2: 
expected result: http://1drv.ms/1uTj8Nd
Div: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEZPjj

Comment: `contain` should respect the image's aspect ratio. Can you add the full Base64-encoded image data to the question?

Comment: I have added link to div with data, it is a bit long so I was not able to post it here

Comment: No problem. It seems to work just fine for me when I modify your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bksmhtwc/3

Comment: I have added picture and new codepen to better show the problem

Comment: Can you post (a mockup of) the expected output? Because I don't see any problem. With `contain`, the image will fit either horizontally or vertically (but not both) depending on the proportions of itself and its container. The only way to show the image completely *+* fill the container completely is to have the container match the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Is update 2 better showing the problem? I am not expecting for the whole space to be filled horizontal or vertical fit will be just fine

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to show the whole picture

Comment: Could you expand on that please? I have been using background-size: contain; with images and it worked just fine